# Chrome Extension Blocked from pulling data for some users

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've got a simple Chrome Extension that allows users to create and modify a library of comments they can add to text entry forms via the right-click menu.

It's optimized for Google Docs and commenting.

Some users are clearly blocked from pulling data from the database and I don't know why - I can't replicate.

You can use the free version to test - it should create a user on the server, then give you a right-click menu ("Annotate") that has sub-items under Argument.

Users with the problem don't see any sub-items because the values aren't pulled from the db.

The data exchange is very simple: the extension pulls a string from a php script on my server, then splits it. Here's the code that pulls the data...

Any thoughts on why some users are blocked?

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('userID', function (results){
    if (typeof results.userID !== 'undefined') {
        userID = results.userID;
            var url = "http://www.11trees.com/XXXXXXXX.php?user=" + userID;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadComplete;
    } else {
        chrome.windows.create({'url': "http://www.11trees.com/XXXXXXX.php"});

    }
});


function loadComplete(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        out = xmlhttp.responseText.split("_000_");
    }
}
```

And the Manifest (maybe I need more permissions?):

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://localhost/*.php/*"]
},
```

**Update**: one specific user with this problem tried both school and personal Google accounts, home and school internet, and multiple devices including a ChromeBook. Through screenshots she confirmed that the extension installs just fine, that she doesn't have any unusual permissions set on her Chrome account.

The 00003.log file is just empty - where there should be a small dataset, downloaded through the script, there is just no content in local storage.

Could it be antivirus that is blocking the download?

**Adding full extension per Xan's request**

```
{

"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Annotate for Chrome",
"short_name": "Annotate",
"description": "Right-click access to a pre-written library of comments. Write     it once, to perfection, and reuse forever!",
"version": "2.5.0.3",

"permissions": ["identity.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/",     "clipboardWrite", "clipboardRead", "activeTab", "tabs", "contextMenus", "storage",     "webNavigation", "*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

"externally_connectable": {
"matches": ["http://*.11trees.com/*.php/*"]},

"oauth2": {
"client_id": "425460661917-    smaehlat7c66p1ns6t90ssj3jmlrrecm.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
]

},

"background": {"scripts": ["/scripts/background.js", "/scripts/buy.js",     "/scripts/accessComments.js", "/scripts/contextMenus.js"]},


"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
"js": ["/scripts/content.js"]
}
],

"icons": {
      "16": "icon.png",
      "48": "icon.png",
      "128": "icon.png"
    },

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": {
    "19": "icon.png",
    "38": "icon.png"
},
"default_title": "Annotate for Google Chrome",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
}

}
```

Comment: Your extension gives each user same-origin access to a server running on their *own machine* (`localhost`)? Does your extension set up a local HTTP server n each user's `localhost` (or expect one to be available)?

Comment: I wondered about the 'localhost' bit...it's why I included that portion of the manifest. My partner did the DB connection...we're clearly hacks:)

So that code snippet might be left over from testing or just copied from somewhere else. I feel like our server should be in there, not localhost. Although the php bit will let the extension hit anything ending in php, I guess?

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: There isn't much to fail here. You are very light on details of what the failure looks like (no requests to your server succeed, some succeed, etc.). Did you examine your own logs? Where are all the error handlers for abnormal responses / network errors?

Comment: Thank you for taking a look, Xan. As a broad question, is there any setting in Chrome (or perhaps institutional setting, since these users are teachers) that could stop Local Storage from being used? The specific user I refer to in my update, who is also a Google Admin at her school, shared a screenshot of her Chrome Content Settings and it was set to 'recommended' - allowing cookies and data.

Can antivirus effect a Chrome Extension?